# Asymptotically Optimal Universal Code In Other Bases

Tags: information-theory, data-compression, coding-theory

Universal codes are fairly well studied, and many asymptotically optimal universal codes exist for binary data (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_(data_compression) especially https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_delta_coding and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_omega_coding).

I know that no optimal universal code can be created (as per [Variable Length Encoding of Integers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/28719/variable-length-encoding-of-integers/28720#28720)).

My question is if there are any known asymptotically optimal universal codes in other bases. For example I feel as though one could construct a universal code in any base using similar methods to the elias delta and omega codes, I just don't know if that would constitute an asymptotically optimal code, nor how best to describe such a code.

Does anybody know or have any references to universal codes in non-binary bases?